# Printing with a receipt printer

Tags: php, printing, epson

I have a receipt printer TM-T88IV with usb access. Is it possible to print something directly to the printer from a .php website? Something like

```
<?
$text=random_text_method();
print_to_local_tm($text);
?>
```

? I have no clue how to get startet.

Comment: I don't see anything in the printer's documentations about php connection.  I would download the windows utility that's available with that and see if you can connect with a php script to get data to print.  If you are willing to go the fairly complicated route you can get a php-usb library and figure out how to use the printer with libusb: https://github.com/oasynnoum/php-usb

Comment: fopen('printers address') fwrite(file)

Comment: how do I get printers address?

Comment: @Adam The printers network address. `192.168.x.y` for example.

Answer (score 0):

If TM-T88IV's USB connection are recognized as COM(serial-port), You can use PHP serial-port extension.

Gorilla(PHP serial-port extension)
https://github.com/oasynnoum/Gorilla

Basic usage of Gorilla
https://gist.github.com/oasynnoum/6076496